# How to launch multiple instances of a application from Main()?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm testing a load balancer, for this i need to run multiple HTTP servers. Right now i can run multiple HTTP servers by creating multiple projects. However i would like to know if it is possible to start multiple instances of a application from just one solution.

For example, i have the following method:

```
    private static void RunLocalHttpServer(int Port)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpListener HttpListener = new HttpListener();
            HttpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:" + Port.ToString() + "/");
            HttpListener.Start();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

This method is called in the main method of my console application, like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] ServerPorts = {8081, 8082, 8083};
        for (int i = 0; i < ServerPorts.Length; i++) {
            RunLocalHttpServer(ServerPorts[i]);
        } 
    }
```

When i run this application it opens one console with a server that is listening on port 8081. However i would like to launch, in this case three seperate consoles, where in each console a server will run (one on port 8081, one on 8082 and one on 8083).

Is it possible to do this from one solution? If not, what can i use as a alternative to accomplish my goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does it need to be in the same solution? Why does it need to be in a VS solution at all? Why not doing it the old-fashioned and simple way by simply using some batch script (or Powershell) to start so-and-so-many instances of your program? (pass the port for each program instance you start as command line argument).

Comment: Why cannot you just run multiple instances of the executable passing port as command line argument ?

Comment: Suppose, maybe you could create a Task for each instance you want to create and wait for them all to finish "get closed".  If you can just run multiple instances of your app & pass in the port number like Dmytro suggested ...

Comment: add your method in a class library created 3 console applications and right click on the solution > property > multiple startup project and launch all 3 console apps at once

Answer (score 0):

> If not, what can i use as a alternative to accomplish my goal?

You can alternatively use [netcat](https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/) to listen on certain ports .